# How to calculate which items are most of the time grouped together?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...     'dtime' : sorted(list(pd.date_range('2020-01-01', periods=3)) * 3),
...     'item': list('ABC') * 3,
...     'group' : [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1]
...     }
... )
>>> df.set_index(['dtime', 'group'])
                 item
dtime      group
2020-01-01 1        A
           1        B
           2        C
2020-01-02 3        A
           3        B
           1        C
2020-01-03 2        A
           1        B
           1        C
```

Each day three items (A, B, C) are grouped. Group names are random.
I have to find out which items are most of the time grouped together.

When we consider data for day 2020-01-01, we can see that items A and B are in the same group, and C is alone. For day 2020-01-02 situation is the same, just groups names are different.
For day 2020-01-03, B and C are in the same group but A is alone.

We have combinations AB, AC, and BC. For each combination I have to calculate percentage of group membership in the following way:

AB - A and B are in the same group in days 2020-01-01 and 2020-01-02, 2 out of 3 days, so they are in the same group (2/3) 66% of the time.

AC - A and C are never in the same group, so their percentage of being in the same group in 0%

BC - B and C are in the same group only for day 2020-01-03, one out of three days, so their percentage is (1/3) 33%

After sorting results:
AB 66%
BC 33%
AC  0%

I can say that in the period of three days AB were most of the time grouped together, than BC.
A and C were never grouped together.

How to get answer like this one from the original dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create combinations `2` per groups, then [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) for counter, add missing values by [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html), sorting by [`Series.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html), multiple by `100`, `round` and last convert tuples in index by `join`:

```
from  itertools import combinations

possible = combinations(df['item'].unique(), 2)

s = (df1.groupby(level=[0,1])['item']
        .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(combinations(x, 2)))
        .value_counts(normalize=True)
        .reindex(possible, fill_value=0)
        .sort_values(ascending=False)
        .mul(100)
        .round()
        .rename(lambda x: ''.join(x)))
print (s)
AB    67.0
BC    33.0
AC     0.0
Name: item, dtype: float64
```

Comment: @user3225309 - Super, glad can help ;)

Comment: you are really skilled with pandas. I really appreciate your solutions. Thanks again. Best regards.

Comment: @user3225309 - Thanks, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)

Comment: Uh, I forgot to do that, but your answer is now accepted. Big thanks.